# Elo based multiplayer matchmaking

Tags: redis, queue, multiplayer, matchmaking

I am trying to build a matchmaking server. Here's my idea this far:
Allow users to queue via websockets, getting player Id, ip, elo, etc.

Place in a real time database like redis as a queue

Scan through the queue trying to find a best batch for the player at the head of the queue.

My issues are, I feel like scanning through is bad, especially as that's only 1 crawler searching through potentially thousands of players. Any tips or resources for handling this? Is it a bad call for my to try to build this myself when I could use something like gamelift or steamworks to host for me? 
Thank you!